# Is there a way to highlight specific months in reat-datepicker Month picker?

Tags: highlight, picker, react-datepicker

I'm trying to highlight specific months in showMonthYearPicker, just like in the default datepicker. I tried few options, none work. Can someone help to figure out a way to do that?

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  highlightDates={[addDays(new Date(), 31)]}
  showMonthYearPicker
/>
```

or even:

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  highlightMonths={[addDays(new Date(), 31)]}
  showMonthYearPicker
/>
```

for example, the desired result would look like that:

[image: example to how it would look like:]